# Change Lan IP Address of router

Tags: networking, lan

I was planning to extend my wifi range to dead zones using another router. Both of my routers have Gateway IP address: **192.168.0.1**. After looking into methods of how to convert router to access point, what I understood is that I have to disable the DHCP server on secondary (access point) router and have to assign LAN IP as same as primary router with different device number, then I have to connect both routers via LAN to LAN port. Now, I have disabled the DHCP server on my secondary router (access point). But I am unable to change the gateway IP. For eg: I tried changing it to 192.168.0.2 or 192.168.0.5. But I am always getting an error as ["Error LAN IP Address"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxAsP.png).

I don't know why is it not changing the LAN IP. Also, there is an option of route mode and Bridge mode for each port in my router, is there anything I have to do with this?
I am new to this stuff and seriously want to resolve it. Can someone please guide me?!. Thanks

Primary Router: NOKIA G-140W-F 
Secondary Router: NOKIA G-140W-F

Comment: Why do you need to change the gateway IP? With the setup you describe, the Gateway IP address will indeed be `192.168.0.1`, which is the IP address of the main router that is the gateway for the entire network. You should also set the secondary router to bridge mode, or access path mode (whatever is available).

Comment: Even though DHCP service is disabled, can you check what the access point's DHCP address pool is set to? It could be that the firmware checks for conflicts even if the service is turned off.

Comment: @harrymc I have tried with assigning both of the router same IP but the connection was unstable (keeps getting re-connected every few seconds) and also, I was not able to login to any of the router portal. Thanks for the advice but the bridge mode didn't work for me.

Comment: @user1686 thank you for the advice, but it seems the issue was with my router software. I have resolved it by the solution mention below (by Daniel B).

Comment: You don't need to assign the secondary router an IP. This is automatically done by the DHCP server of the main router; if the secondary router is setup correctly it is just a DHCP client the same as your computer.

Answer (score 1):

The unfortunate truth is that most consumer router software is truly terrible. It may simply reject any address that is not *x.x.x.1*. That doesn't mean what you want is impossible, it'll just make accessing the web UI later inconvenient.

Try with *192.168.254.1*. To access the web interface later, you will have to manually change the client device's IP address to be in *192.168.254.0/24*. Then back after you're done so you can access the regular network again.

Wi-Fi access point functionality will not be impacted by this change.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is true that my routers reject any IP which is not of x.x.x.1 format. I have assigned 192.168.254.1 and its range to one of my router as mentioned by you. Both of them are providing me my fast internet :). The only issue is that I can't access the login portal of my second router with this connection. I have to disconnect the lan cable and then only I can access it. But it is not a concern for me right now.